# Connecting the Wii remote to a computer via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, wii, remote, mac

How do i connect a Wii remote to my Mac via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to pair the Wiimote to the Mac via BT, but you need an application to actually read the data.

http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/02/use-your-wii-remote-on-your-mac.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where the data would go after it got to your Mac, but there is Osculator http://www.osculator.net/wp/ which outputs OSC and MIDI messages if it's for musical applications (as well as others)
If you program in Python there are a number of implementations there
If you are using micros here is an interface board for Arduino that connects to the numchuck

Answer (score 0):

connecting the remote to via bluetooth at the driver level is rather typical.  but the question is how you wish to use the remote. as others have suggested you can use python, arduino or etc.  I would suggest using processing, if you are atune to a little programming and bit twiddling.  I have some [code over here](http://ittybits.blogspot.com/2008/06/visualization-of-accelerometer-objects.html) that will give a 3D representation of the current orientation of the wii remote (see image). This was written in Processing and the code is documented so that beginners to Processing can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a wiiremote with my mac mini, all you ned to do is pair the device. I then use MAX MSP to handle all the data, you could just access the bluetooth port directly, but there's a handy object called aka.wiiremote, it's available for free here -> http://www.iamas.ac.jp/~aka/max/ this object will allow MAX MSP to receive and send data to the remote, without any ugly scaling or formating, it makes the whole programming process 100x faster. I've got a whole bunch of programs I've made to turn the wiiremote into a music controller, I mostly use it to wiiJ (wii DJing) using Ableton live. I also use the wiiremote as an infra red camera for a digital graffiti setup, you just pair it with the mac then download the whiteboard software from here -> http://www.uweschmidt.org/wiimote-whiteboard it's free and works really well, the setup is simple.